# Sending message to a changing number of endpoints using Camel http4

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have created the following piece of code and, instead of just one endpoint, I want to send the same JSON body to multiple endpoints using camel HTTP4. The number of endpoints is likely to change over time.

```
                    .choice()
                        .when(simple("${body} != null"))
                              .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant("POST"))
                              .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_URI, simple(url))
                              .setProperty("ObjectBody", body())
                              .to("http4://someEndpoint?throwExceptionOnFailure=true&httpClient.socketTimeout=300000")
                        .otherwise()
                            .log(LoggingLevel.ERROR, "Incoming request has empty body")
                        .endChoice()
                    .end()
```

I'm trying to figure out the best way to configure and use multiple endpoints in this scenario.

I have looked at the Multicast EIP, but it looks like I would have to know the number of endpoints beforehand.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The (dynamic in your case) `recipientList` is what you need !
See https://camel.apache.org/components/3.14.x/eips/recipientList-eip.html

Answer (score 0):

Did you take a look at RouteBox?

> THE NEED FOR A CAMEL ROUTEBOX ENDPOINT The routebox component is
> designed to ease integration in complex environments needing a large
> collection of routes and involving a wide set of endpoint technologies
> needing integration in different ways
>
> In such environments, it is often necessary to craft an integration
> solution by creating a sense of layering among camel routes
> effectively organizing them into
>
> Coarse grained or higher level routes - aggregated collection of inner
> or lower level routes exposed as Routebox endpoints that represent an
> integration focus area. For example

https://camel.apache.org/components/2.x/routebox-component.html

Its usage:

```
from ("direct:sendToMapBasedRoutebox")
    .setHeader("ROUTE_DISPATCH_KEY", constant("addToCatalog"))
    .to("routebox:multipleRoutes?innerRegistry=#registry&routeBuilders=#routes&dispatchMap=#map")
    .to("log:Routes operation performed?showAll=true");
```

Then in theory this should fan out the requests towards all (routes) encapsulated by a RouteBox.